# ¿Cómo montar carpeta compartida en virtualbox (Anfitrion Windows - Huesped xUbunto)?

Tags: xubuntu

Tengo instalado Ubunto 16.04.3 LTS como invitado en una máquina virtual de VirtualBox corriendo en un computador SO Windows 10.

Con el siguiente comando trato de montar una carpeta compartida llamada "temp".

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 temp /home/$(whoami)/compartida
```

obteniendo el siguiente mensaje de error

> wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on temp, missing codepage or helper program, or other error

Al revisar el log:

```
dmesg | tail
```

> vboxsf: Successfully loaded version 5.1.16_Ubunto
>
> sf_read_super_aux err=-22

**Edit: [Pasos seguidos](https://askubuntu.com/a/30446)**

1) Instalar Guest Additions

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
VBoxManage --version
5.0.40_Ubuntor115130
```

2) Usuarios en Ubunto deben estar en el grupo `vboxsf`

```
sudo groupadd vboxsf
groupadd: el grupo <<vboxsf>> ya existe
sudo usermod -aG vboxsf $(whoami)
```

3) Definir una carpeta en Windows para ser compartida con Ubunto utilizando el la interfaz de VirtualBox (Dispositivos/Carpetas Compartidas/Preferencias de Carpetas Compartidas/Agregar Nueva carpeta)

3.1) Carpeta en Windows `E:\temp`, llamada `temp` en la interfaz de VirtualBox

4) Crear un punto de montaje en Ubunto.

```
mkdir /home/$(whoami)/compartida
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solución](https://askubuntu.com/a/851054/706956):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms
```

Reiniciar